# How to reset libreoffice dictionaries to factory defaults?

Tags: libreoffice, settings, default, reset, dictionary

By mistake I have added a wrong word to my libreoffice dictionary. now I have checked my ignore list and it is not there but still if I type that wrong word it is not underlined as wrong. I want to remove that word from dictionary. Please tell me how can I reset all the dictionaries to factory default settings.

Answer (score 1):

While Opening the Liber office

In tools menu ---> Select Options

Under language Settings ----> Select Writing Aids

[image: Look At this Image]

Delete your Words what ever you have added from the List .